# How to build a suffix array in Java 7+ in linear space?

Tags: java, algorithm, suffix-array

In Pre-java 7, I could simply do the following:

```
public static String[] suffixes(String s)
{
    int N = s.length();
    String[] suffixes = new String[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    suffixes[i] = s.substring(i, N);
    return suffixes;
}
```

However, in Java 7, the substring method returns a new string. So the space consumed will be `O(n^2)` where `n` is the length of the string.

Any quick and easy way to do the same in Java 7 and higher versions?

Comment: Not with a `String`. No. If you used a `List<Character>`, then `List.subList` is a view on the underlying `List`.

Comment: One way would be to have my own String implementation, which behaves like the Java 6 implementation, but surely we can do something better right?

Comment: `String` is `final` - it cannot be subclassed.

Comment: It's... *always* returned a new `String`...  If you thought you were getting better performance because it wasn't, you were quite misled.

Comment: @Makoto Yes. But the substring [didn't copy the underlying data](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/). This changed in Java 7, when the data was copied for `substring` to avoid a very short substring of a massive `String` causing memory issues.

Comment: @BoristheSpider By implementation I meant to have my own class that mimics the string, using a char array or maybe delegating to string private var.

Comment: @Makoto Before Java 7, `substring` would return a new `String` object that *reused* the backing `char[]`. This is what OP is referring to.

Comment: How many strings are you doing this for, and what are their lengths? What I mean is, does the `O(n^2)` space complexity really matter?

Comment: @rents is this (provably) an issue? Given the number of new `String` objects the average program creates, it's likely this isn't a performance bottleneck...

Comment: Do you generate the String[N] substrings because you *might* need them? How often do you need each substring? Is the algorithm behind this "best choice"?

Comment: @PaulBoddington Its more of a thought exercise rather than doing in some real-world code.

Comment: @laune suppose I am doing a longest repeated substring problem using a suffix array. I know that the suffix tree would be the way to go.

Comment: @rents Ok, I see. I think the answer is that there is no way to do it without writing your own string-like class that works the way `String` used to.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly invent an Abstract Data Type to represent a "suffix array":

- Initialized with String
- Stores the String it received and nothing else
- Provides accessor methods as necessary, for example:

  - `size()`
  - `get(int n)` - return the n-th element
  - `equals(int n, String s)` - compare the n-th element with input
  - ...

Depending on the functionality you expect from this structure, it might make sense to store the underlying String in a different format, for example as a `char[]`, or even both. It doesn't really matter, that will be an implementation detail, encapsulated, hidden from users of your ADT. Start by creating an `interface` and define the method it needs to support.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own String (or Suffix) class, as in

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/63suffix/SuffixArray.java.html

Comment: Excellent. I have an older version of the book but this one has the updated code.